# Unable to deploy MuleSoft project file, file does not exist

Tags: jar, mule, archive, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I am unable to export Mule Project using:
Right click on Project -> Export -> Mule -> Anypoint Studio Project to Mule Deployable Archive (includes Studio metadata).

[image]

I have tried to create empty jar file and assign export to it, still the same error, also tried to change directories to cloud disk as well as local locations, always the same issue. Cannot get anyone to support with it and I could not find any similar issue in the Internet.

Mule version: 4.2.1
Anypoint Studio Version: 7.4.2

The thing is that I know that this file does not exist, I know that because I want to create this file. Manual creation and assignment did not work so I have no clue why is Mule throwing such a strange error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple possible causes for this issue. First you should ensure that the application is building correctly before trying to export it. Most of the time a Maven build problem prevents the export to work. That is because Studio 7.x uses Maven to build and package Mule applications. If Maven execution fails it just can't create the output file. That is different than in Studio 6.x in case you were used to that version.

It is possible that the error log link in the error can give some insight on the details of the issue.

In the past sometimes an error like this was related to a Studio bug though I believe they were fixed by now. You are using an old version of Anypoint Studio. The current one at this time is Studio 7.11. It is recommended to stay on top of newer versions to receive bug fixes and improvements. Note that specifically Studio 7.4.2 can not auto update to newer versions. You need to do a fresh install of the newer version.

Comment: Thanks for these information, currently we cannot move to newer version as it breaks a few things (don't know why yet). Also application is struggling with its builds, it is not stable as multiple plugins are using multiple servers. I guess the only solution for these issues is to try to build application without "failed" status and then without chaning anything just export it. We had some issues with exporting as is, but we have found a way to just remove troublemaking plugins temporarily. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If it doesn't build it will probably not be able to export. I'm not sure about the issues upgrading Studio version, however if possible I recommend the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an issue.

pom.xml had a non-working plugin: Cakupan. This plugin was working on Lead local setup, but not on developer ones, so we had to comment it out (it provided no functionality in case of our dev, but we have no idea where it is being used).
Troublemaking plugin should not be affecting negatively simple .jar creation, but instead of it:

1. Try to create .jar
2. Unable to create .jar, processing creation
3. Jar created, but could not be found (as it failed and was not created)

I think no stack trace caused a few hours delay and Mulesoft should update this troubleshooting as it had provided no value to us, so either it should fail at the beginning with correct error (without possibility to continue) or allow file creation with everything packaged and if plugin works or not should be based on environment when it runs.